# how to choose which editor should open file at idea

Tags: intellij-idea, preferences

I'm newly at Intellij Idea.

`rmnHibernateConfiguration.hb` is open as easy file. It shows gibberish:

```
��
```

I couldn't find how to open this file types as Hibernate file?

This settings isn't so intuitive as at eclipse.

- ***How to change opening file preferences at idea?***

Comment: I haven't looked into it before, but you might be able to configure something with IntelliJ's [external tools configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-tools.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to open it in IDEA (including any IDEA plug-ins), you configure it in *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > File Types*. Also, some plug-ins may have a setting to define what file types to handle. But that is dependent on

If you want to open in an external program/application, you will need to write an external tool definition as ajp15243 suggests. You will not be able to double click (to the best of my knowledge) the file. But you can select it and then launch the external tool definition (you can map to a keyboard shortcut). The external tool definition can use one of the predefined macro to pass the selected file in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Settings | File Types